# Char* and byte* equality comparison (numbers and text)

Tags: c, string, char, type-conversion

I have the following a char* key which is a char array that can contain either integers or text. So the key can have value 3 or tom for example

I have a byte* data array which contains stored data. I need to test whether the key is equal to the data.

My logic is currently along the lines of:

```
int j = 0 ;
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    sprintf(key_cmp, "%02x", (ulong)*data++);
}
if (!strcmp(key, key_cmp)) fprintf(stderr, "Equal \n");
```

I realise this code is incorrect as i am trying to print as hex rather than char here...  but when I try to use %02x, garbage gets printed out.

How can I also ensure that 01 and 1 will be treated as equal? I realise that this may vary on byte ordering, hence I can't think of a general solution. I'd like to avoid using atoi so was wondering if there was another method (mostly because I have no real way of knowing whether the key is an integer or not)

Thanks

Comment: I know it may seem overkill, but did you consider converting one to the other, then just doing a `memcmp()` or a `strcmp()` Ultimately that is all you're doing now anyway, just one byte at a time. If you're trying to multi-purpose the input you're in for a long road of frustration. To that go find the architecture-astronaut that decided "but strings and numbers are really just bytes, so they're really analogous" and unplug his oxygen.

Comment: *"a char array that can contain either integers or text"* - it's important to know exactly what kind of data you are working with.

Comment: In this is part of a storage engine which is not typed. Hence this isn't achievable.

Comment: sounds to me like you'd better convert your strings into numbers and compare numbers.

Comment: Since you are in a very specific situation, why not try to implement it yourself ? String -> integer, with a fallback value if the string contains non-numeric characters, is not very complicated.

Comment: Are you saying convert each character/byte to its hex representation and compare that, ignoring leading 0s?

Answer (score 1):

The guess is your problem is that `%02x` is the format for an `int` not a `unsigned long` - so you're on system where `sizeof(int)!=sizeof(long)` that will cause a problem.

See [Wiki][1] for a description of format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Because char[] is 1 byte and byte[] is 1 byte it would be easier to compare them as byte arrays (unsigned char). Either will do the same thing without any special formatting.

```
memcmp(key,data,len)
strcmp(key,data,len)
```